# How do i display random products from products table in mysql

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How do l display products randomly on my laravel estore.
[image: i have this mysql database with table products]

I want the code to pick 10 random products and display using foreach preferably
[image: Thus the image of where i want products displayed randomly]

```
<section class="sec-padding trending-product-sec">
    <div class="custom-container">
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>Trending  <span>Products</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="owl-carousel custom-arrow" id="trending-slider">
                    @foreach($latests as $product)
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="trending-product">  
                                <div class="add-wish">
                                    <form class="addtowishlist-form">
                                        {{csrf_field()}}
                                        @if(Session::has('uniqueid'))
                                            <input type="hidden" name="uniqueid" value="{{Session::get('uniqueid')}}">
                                        @else
                                            <input type="hidden" name="uniqueid" value="{{str_random(7)}}">
                                        @endif
                                        
                                        <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{$product->title}}">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$product->id}}">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="">
                                        <input type="hidden" id="cost" name="cost" value="{{$product->price}}">
                                       
                                        <i class="fa fa-heart-o product-addWishlist-btn to-wishlist"  id="{{$product->id}}" aria-hidden="true" att="0"></i>
                        
                                    </form>
                                    
                                </div>
                                   <a href="{{url('/product')}}/{{$product->id}}/{{$product->title}}">  <img class="img-responsive" src="{{url('/timthumb.php?src=/assets/images/products')}}/{{$product->feature_image}}&amp;w=700&amp;h=443" alt="Product Image">
                                    <h5>{{$product->title}}</h5></a>
                                    <p> {{ substr(str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', strip_tags($product->description)), 0, 600)}}</p>
                                    <ul class="price-list">
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>{{$product->price}}</li>
                                        @if($product->rocketdelivery == 'yes')
                                        <li>
                                            <img class="rocket-delivery" src="{{ URL::asset('kumba/images/rocket-delivery.png')}}">
                                        </li>
                                        @else
                                        <li></li>
                                        @endif
                                    </ul>
                                    @if($product->bylocal == 'yes')
                                        <img class="buy-local" src="{{ URL::asset('kumba/images/buy-local.png')}}">
                                    @endif
                                    <div class="ratings">
                                        <div class="empty-stars"></div>
                                        <div class="full-stars" style="width:{{\App\Review::ratings($product->id)}}%">
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div> 
                                    <form class="addtocart-form text-center">
                                        {{csrf_field()}}
                                        @if(Session::has('uniqueid'))
                                            <input type="hidden" name="uniqueid" value="{{Session::get('uniqueid')}}">
                                        @else
                                            <input type="hidden" name="uniqueid" value="{{str_random(7)}}">
                                        @endif
                                        <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="{{$product->price}}">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{$product->title}}">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{$product->id}}">
                                        <input type="hidden" id="cost" name="cost" value="{{$product->price}}">
                                        <input type="hidden" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1">
                                        <input type="hidden" id="size" name="size" value="">
                                        @if($product->stock != 0 || $product->stock === null )

                                            <button type="button" class="custom-btn product-addCart-btn to-cart"><i class="margin-right-5 fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$language->add_to_cart}}</button>
                                            
                                        @else
                                            <button type="button" class="custom-btn product-addCart-btn to-cart" disabled><i class="margin-right-5 fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$language->out_of_stock}}</button>
                                        @endif
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So this is how my developer was displaying but not efficient. So how do i display products as l took over the project. I have tried many methods but none are working. Am still new to laravel

Comment: And where is your problem? Where is your controller code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inRandomOrder()` to get `Products` in a random order:

```
$products = Product::inRandomOrder()->take(10)->get();
```

The above will get 10 random `products` for you and from there you can pass them to your view or wherever it is you need to use your random products. For example:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::inRandomOrder()->take(10)->get();
    return view('products.index', compact('products'));
}
```

Then in your `products.view` blade file, you can just loop over the products as usual:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <p>{{ $product->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Based on your comment with the following:

```
$latests = Product::where('status','1')->orderBy('id','desc')->take(8)->get();
```

If what you actually want is the `10` most recent records but in a random order, use the [`shuffle`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-shuffle) method available on Laravel collections:

```
$latests = Product::where('status', '1')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get()
    ->shuffle();
```

Comment: ok thank you so i jst add it on my code that i send?

Comment: so the public function i add it under which part of my source code

Comment: @JimuCollins You add the `$products = Product::inRandomOrder()->take(10)->get();` to your function that in turn displays your trending products view.

Comment: am having issues locating the part of the source code where my developer defined his functions. How do i locate them

Comment: You search or ask the other developer. The `web.php` route file is usually a good starting point, then follow the trail. Can't really help you on that part.

Comment: ok thank you.. is there any way to search

Comment: the built in search functionality in vs code is only search in an opened source code page only

Comment: are u ok with i sharing my source code with u

Comment: @JimuCollins VSCode can search through your entire project. Use `CTRL+SHIFT+F` on Windows/Linux or `CMD+SHIFT+F` on Mac.

Comment: $latests = Product::where('status','1')->orderBy('id','desc')->take(8)->get(); i figured out that in his controllers he used this way so hw do i refactor it in ur own code so that it displays random top 10

Comment: @JimuCollins I have updated my answer to what I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller use RAND

```
$products = Product::orderByRaw('RAND()')->take(10)->get();

 return view('your.view page', compact('products'));
```

In the view page loop through @foreach

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <p> {!! $product->image!!} </p>
    <p> {!! $product->name !!} </p>
//more code here
@endforeach
```